# Change page data based on currency choice

Tags: opencart

I've been trying to create simple script that swaps table data based on the active currency code. It's for a size chart (on product.tpl).

**PREMISE:**
IF "USD" is active then display table "A" (Inches), ELSE display table "B" (Centimeters).

I'm a total hack with php/js, but enough to find my way into trouble. :)
I followed this thread to bring the currency code variable into "product.tpl": [How to get currency to show on product page in opencart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919496/how-to-get-currency-to-show-on-product-page-in-opencart)

Now I'm just banging my head, I can't find the right variable to create the swap... I've tried multiple variations of a simple If/Else script, basically like this:

```
<?php if ($currency['code'] == $currency_code) { ?>
    <td>15.5"</td>
    <td>25"</td>
<?php } else { ?>
    <td >40cm</td>
    <td >64cm</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Anyone have a clue what the script might look like?
Or am I totally barking at the wrong cat here?? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the session value for the currency code...

```
<?php if($this->session->data['currency'] == 'USD') : ?>
<td>15.5"</td>
<td>25"</td>
<?php else: ?>
<td>40cm</td>
<td>60cm</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, works perfectly! I thought that type of statement was used previous to the IF/ELSE, like in the controller files. Very cool!